# Scatter plot markers color based on custom scale

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, colors, scatter-plot

I want to color my scatter points based on a custom color scale but I got this error

ValueError: 'c' argument has 150 elements, which is inconsistent with 'x' and 'y' with size 100.

For the example below, it seems like the length of t needs to be the same as x and y.
However, I want to color the points with a wider scale, for example -50 to 150 instead of 0 to 100.

How can I do this?
Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
t = np.arange(100)
plt.scatter(x, y, c=t)
plt.show()
```

Comment: 't' needs to have 100 entries - one for each `x`, `y`. Above code will use default palette `viridis` to plot this. You can change it to -50 to 150, but the number of entries need to be 100 (count). It won't make a difference in terms of color. Perhaps explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Redox Thanks for your reply. I guess I wasn't clear about what I wanted to achieve. So, x, y, and t are correlated, and I want to have a scatter plot of x and y, then the color (or size) of the markers is correlated to t. At the same time, I want the color scale to be wider than the range of t itself. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Currently, it is using the default palette of `viridis`. You can say `cmap='jet`, etc. if you want to change the palette. But, it will split the colors within that range into 1/100th and give you each color. If you want to change to specific colors, you can provide 100 colors and it will plot accordingly. But human eye can clearly detect ~10-12 colors, so that is more of the restriction. Wider will not help because the first and last colors are the same for a palette. It will plot in that color range. More info on palettes [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your goal is, so I present you two answers: hopefully one is the one you are looking for.

##### First:

Simply create an array `t` of 100 elements ranging from -50 to 150:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
t = np.linspace(-50, 150, len(x))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(x, y, c=t)
fig.colorbar(sc, label="value")
plt.show()
```

[image]

##### Second:

Create an array `t` with 100 elements, ranging from 0 to 100. Asks matplotlib to visualize this colors in the range from -50 to 150.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
t = np.arange(100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(x, y, c=t, vmin=-50, vmax=150)
fig.colorbar(sc, label="value")
plt.show()
```

[image]